# In WIndows, how to change the default icon for all *files* that don't have a specific icon?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I remember I could do that in older Windows versions, up to XP I believe, by changing the registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\DefaultIcon, but that doesn't work since Windows 7, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File types that are not registered with the system and files with no extension are assigned a generic icon from `shell32.dll` by default. The unknown or generic icon for unregistered file types and extensionless files can be customized as follows.

This setting is found in the registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\DefaultIcon
```

The `(default)` or the unnamed value points by default to :
`%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,0`

Using the Registry Editor (regedit.exe), you can change the `(default)` value so that it points to any `.ico` file or to an icon resource inside a `.dll` or `.exe` file by mentioning the file name and resource identifier.

For more information see the article
[How to Change the Icon for a File Type in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-default-icon-file-type-windows/).

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: also, thanks for the link, it's very good .. I had forgotten about the FileExts key